Formating my manuscript with the APA 7th style in Editorial Manager (EM)
I am trying to submit my manuscript to an academic journal that uses Editorial Manager (EM). The journal uses the APA 7th style. The Biblatex appears to be the only way to format my manuscript with the APA 7th, but EM does not use Biber, and I cannot successfully compile the citations. I wrote something like the following:
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{reference.bib}
\begin{filecontents*}{reference.bib}
    @Manual{r2024,
        author = {{R Core Team}},
        year = {2024},
        title = {{R}: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
        organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
        address = {Vienna, Austria},
        url = {https://www.R-project.org/}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\shorttitle{My study}
\begin{document}
I am citing R \parencite{r2024}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

I don't think there's a way around this, if the source is being compiled by the EM backend. I assume they are using standard bibtex methods. If they support apacite, it implements APA6, which depending on the complexity of your references may end up being equivalent to APA7 (although I don't know the fine details of the changes from 6 to 7).

In this case you probably need to get in touch with journal staff and check how to proceed. For BibTeX there is only apacite which gives APA6. For APA7 you either need biblatex and Biber or LuaLaTeX and https://ctan.org/pkg/citation-style-language. I imagine neither of those options runs easily on EM.

I appreciate your comments. I ended up using the apacite package and manually changed the style to the APA 7th style. It's cumbersome but appears to be the only solution.
